# Is it deemed off-topic to ask how come that many commercial companies rely on a specific freeware software?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I'd like to ask the reason why many commercial software companies are using a freeware tool for their product lifecycle by giving the company which produces this tool an advantage and the power to put a commercial license on it / restrict its usage to commercial ends.

Is such a question off-topic for programmers.stackexchange.com? At first I would say no, but I decided to ask here on meta before posting it.

Comment: I don't think the question would fit the main site, but you should try asking in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a question is likely to be closed for being [primarily opinion based](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6491/).
Although subjective questons are welcome here to a certain degree, there are limits. See also [**Good subjective, Bad subjective**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

The problem with your question, as I interpret it from the characterisation that you gave, is that it calls for speculation and not for expertise in the subject matter.